# how to assign unique id to elements that are created dynamically - Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, dynamic, element, unique

Hello im trying to generate dynamic divs with a textbox and delete button in it. On form submit i want all dynamically generated textboxes values, how can i assign unique id to the textbox element. The ID's / Name of textbox should be unique.. to get all values properly.
Pls suggest..

My Code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic elements</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function addRow(divId) {
        count = 0;
        count++;

        var parentDiv = document.getElementById(divId);

        // create a div dynamically
        var eleDiv = document.createElement("div");
        eleDiv.setAttribute("name", "olddiv");
        eleDiv.setAttribute("id", "olddiv");

         // create a textbox dynamically
        var eleText = document.createElement("input");
        eleText.setAttribute("type", "text");
        eleText.setAttribute("name", 'textbox' + count);
        eleText.setAttribute("id", "textbox");

        // create a delete button dynamically
        var eleBtn = document.createElement("input");
        eleBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
        eleBtn.setAttribute("value", "delete");
        eleBtn.setAttribute("name", "button");
        eleBtn.setAttribute("id", "button");
        eleBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteRow('button')");

        // append new div to parent div 
        parentDiv.appendChild(eleDiv);

        // append textbox & button to new div 
        eleDiv.appendChild(eleText);
        eleDiv.appendChild(eleBtn);

    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
            var div = document.getElementById('olddiv');
            if (div) {
                div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
            }
    }

</SCRIPT>
```

```
<form name="objForm" action="test1.php">
    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
    <div id="dataTable" width="350px"><INPUT type="text" name="txtData" /></div>
    <input  type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly you could try:

```
var textboxCount = 0;

/* In your function */
// create a textbox dynamically
var eleText = document.createElement("input");
eleText.setAttribute("type", "text");
eleText.setAttribute("name", 'textbox' + count);
eleText.setAttribute("id", "textbox" + textboxCount);
textboxCount += 1; //Increment the count
```

That will create textbox's with id's `textbox0`, `textbox1`, `textbox2` etc.

Or, for a more efficient option you may store all textboxs you create in an array, like so:

```
var textboxes = new Array();

/* In your function */
// create a textbox dynamically
var eleText = document.createElement("input");
eleText.setAttribute("type", "text");
eleText.setAttribute("name", 'textbox' + count);

textboxes.push(eleText);
```

Now instead of calling `e = document.getElementById('textbox4');` you may call `e = textboxes[4];`

Comment: Oh it was this simple... Thanks... Fr helping.

Answer (score 5):

You can keep a global count variable (outside of function divId).
Each time you create a new div, you add 1 to the counter and use it as a unique ID for your textbox.

```
<script language="javascript">
    var globalcount=0;
    function addRow()
    {
         globalcount++;
         //the rest
    }

</script>
```

And the rest is much like you already do for the name.

Comment: Tried (as in: past tense)? and you didn't succeed?

Answer (score -1):

This function will generate a unique ID:

```
function uniqueId() {
    var uid;
    do {
        uid = 'uid-' + Math.random();
    } while (document.getElementById(uid));
    return uid;
}
```

Comment: Do not use this solution, as it may create duplicates, and after 100000 elements it is guaranteed to create duplicates, although it is highly likely a duplicate will occur before that.

Comment: There's still a high chance of a duplicate forming earlier.

Comment: No need for rand - not efficient and might get duplicates, even if creating two objects!!

Comment: yes.. i agree with [Andrew Dunn](http://stackoverflow.com/users/451672/andrew-dunn)

Comment: @AndrewDunn there you go, I removed the `*` and floor, since `.` is allowed in ids anyway. Now its a 1 in 10 Quadrillion chance. And performance wise, its insignificant.

Comment: @Kuf the client's memory would run out due to a massively heavy `DOM` decades before any efficiency problems would become apparent.

Comment: @MichaelRobinson keeping a global variable as PoeHaH suggested will be much more efficient than calling `Math.random()` and since both run on client side, creating an array is cheaper than loading the rand() code. Anyway, [when there's no need for outside functions, why use one?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)